# What happens to the voltage?

Tags: electrical-engineering

Ohms law defines R = V / I, so according to this equation, when resistance increases, voltage and current decreases.
Now i have two questions.

1. Ain't there somekind of "pressure" buildup in front of a resistor? because the resistor limits the current flow, I would expect something like a "traffic jam".
2. How is it that a resistor reduces the voltage? Is it converted to heat by electrons "bumping" into more massive particles or does something else happens to the voltage?

**Edit**

*Wasabi*:
Sorry if this question doesn't have the correct tag, didn't know which tag to give. If you have any suggestions for tags i'll put that in.

*hazzey*:

I'm trying to visualize for myself how Volt\Amp\Resistance work togather.

I understand that Voltage is a measurement of potential energy expressed in Jouls / Coulomb and the Current is the number of Coulombs per second passing a certain point, the only part that isn't quite clear to me is the resistance. How resistance physically works to reduce current and in the process uses some energy (voltage).

If I understand the answer correctly, the following is true.
The voltage that is used by a resistor is always converted to heat.

So if I have a circuit with a single resistor of 1 Ohms with 1 Amp of current, the resulting 1 volt is converted to heat?

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic, since this question has nothing to do with engineering.

Comment: I think this question is too broad. You can't ask for explanations that have similies ("like a traffic jam", or "pressure") while also asking about what happens at the molecular physics level.  Maybe you can specifically ask for more detail about one specific property of electricity after you have shown what you do understand. Otherwise, the answerers won't know where to start in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If resistance increases, voltage increases and current decreases. The extra energy is spent thermally, which is why the resistor gets hot when current flows through it, and the higher the resistance, the hotter it becomes for the same current.

You have to remember that voltage is a differential measurement, like pressure or altitude: you always measure a voltage relative to something or a reference (like earth). Current, on the other hand, is measured when flowing through something, like flow rate.

A good analogy would be water flowing through a dam or similar flow restriction. The more you restrict the water flow (i.e. the higher the resistance becomes), the lower the water flow through the dam, but the higher the pressure upstream of the dam.

Comment: Is the energy/voltage by a resistor always converted to heat? Where does the heat come from? from electrons bumping into other particles or is it some property of the electrical field that produces friction or something?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know, the extra electrical energy is always dissipated as heat. There are different types of resistor construction (see for example http://www.learnabout-electronics.org/Resistors/resistors_08.php), but generally it involves a an electrically and also thermally conductive material (e.g. wire-wound) where the current passes through. Because not all the electrical energy can get through due to the restriction imposed by the resistor, it has to go somewhere and the path of least resistance for it is thermal. Not sure about the underlying physics of it though.

Comment: "No. If resistance increases, voltage increases and current decreases." ... Not exactly ... Ohms law describes how resistance relates to voltage across the resistor and current through the resistor, but your statement does not follow. Consider a resistor across a constant voltage source. If you increase the resistance, the constant voltage does not change, but the current decreases. Now consider a resistor in series with a constant current source. Increase the resistance, the current remains constant, but the voltage drop across the resistor increases. "and/or" would be more accurate.

Comment: @Tut fair point, thanks for the clarification.